# Use named_scopes from a model, with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

Is there any way to reuse named scopes defined in a model, in another model.

I have some generic named_scopes defined that do some filtering, and I would like to use them in another model.Copying them to the new model seems a bit to non-dry.

PS: I'm using Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just write them into a file that you put in the lib directory and include them in each of the models. That way the named scopes will be included in each of the models you include them within.